# Заменить 2 цифры в числе так, чтобы оно стало наибольшим за O(n)

Tags: c++, python, алгоритм, строки, числа

> Дано число, в записи которого может присутствовать до 10^5 цифр. В
>   этом числе можно поменять любые две цифры местами. Среди всех этих
>   замен нужно найти ту, при которой получается наибольшее число.

За *O(n²)* решается легко. Как решить за *O(n)* или за *O(n⋅log(n))*?

Примеры:

```
1234 => 4231
9997754321 => 9997754321
```

Comment: Второй пример какой-то совсем не показательный. И что подразумевается под `заменить`? Поменять местами?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Запишем цифры первоначального числа в массив `a`. (Если цифр у числа много, то скорее всего число вам уже дано именно в таком виде.) Скопируем массив в массив `b` и отсортируем его в порядке убывания.

Найдём первый индекс такой, что `a[i] != b[i]`. Если такого индекса нет, перестановка не нужна, порядок оптимальный. Пусть это индекс `k`. Очевидно, `b[k] >= a[i]` для `i >= k`, причём `b[k] != a[k]` по выбору `k`. Значит, `b[k]` — максимальное из оставшихся чисел.

Очевидно, `b[k]`, `b[k+1]`, ... — перестановка чисел `a[k]`, `a[k+1]`, ..., поэтому `b[k] == a[l]` для некоторого `l > k`. (`l != k`, т. к. `b[k] != a[k]`). Возьмём наибольшее такое `l`.

Перестановка индексов `k` и `l` — искомая.

---

Сложность: O(*n* log *n*) { сортировка } + O(*n*) { поиск *k* } + O(*n*) { поиск *l* } = O(*n* log *n*).

---

**Обновление:** Поскольку мы сортируем цифры, то сложность сортировки можно уменьшить до O(*n*), применив [сортировку подсчётом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC). Итоговая сложность O(*n*).

---

**Примечание**: Можно избавится от дополнительного массива `b`, если заменить его просто на количество 9-ок, 8-ок, 7-ок и т. д. (эта информация используется в сортировке подсчётом), за счёт некоторого усложнения кода. Таким образом мы получаем всего лишь O(1) дополнительной памяти.

Comment: А просто 2 прохода (*O(n)*) сортировки с поиском максимума не достаточно?

Comment: @avp: Уточнил ответ.

Comment: Точно. Маленький доп. массив (кстати, я подумал и понял, что простая сортировка с максимумом не решает, поскольку 2 самые большие цифры уже м.б. в начале числа)

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ

Comment: @SergeyPestov: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3):

Вот реализация на Питоне линейного (`O(n)`) алгоритма c постоянной дополнительной памятью (`O(1)`), описанного в [ответе @VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/576191/23044):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from collections import Counter

def make_largest_by_swapping_2_digits(digits):
    """O(n) time, O(m) space"""
    # find where given number differs from the largest number with the same digits
    multiplicity = Counter(digits) # count how many times each digit occurs
    all_digits = sorted(multiplicity, reverse=True) # m digits in decreasing order
    largest = (d for d in all_digits for _ in range(multiplicity[d]))
    for k, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(digits, largest)):
        if a != b:
            break
    else: # already largest possible
        return # nothing to swap

    # find on the right where a == b
    j = next(len(digits) - i for i, a in enumerate(reversed(digits), 1) if a == b)
    digits[k], digits[j] = digits[j], digits[k] # swap
```

Пример:

```py
digits = [1,2,3,4]
print('before', *digits)
make_largest_by_swapping_2_digits(digits)
print('after ', *digits)
```

#### Результат

```py
before 1 2 3 4
after  4 2 3 1
```

Заметки по коду:

- [`Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) просто считает сколько раз каждая цифра встречается:

  ```py
  print(Counter(str(9997754321)))
  # -> Counter({'9': 3, '7': 2, '5': 1, '4': 1, '3': 1, '2': 1, '1': 1})
  ```

  Потребление памяти `O(m)`, где m не более 10 для десятичной системы. Можно считать константой.

  Counter по сути multiset здесь (набор цифр с повторениями). Если ограничить тип цифр только целыми десятичными, то можно простой массив использовать вместо Counter:

  ```py
  multiplicity = [0] * 10
  for d in digits:
      multiplicity[d] += 1
  ```
- `largest` это наибольшее число, составленное из тех же цифр что и входное число. Для представления используется генератор, поэтому дополнительная память нужна только для одной цифры в каждый момент `O(1)`
- `enumerate(zip())` позволяет обойти две последовательности одновременно по одной паре элементов за раз, отслеживая текущий индекс:

  ```py
  >>> list(enumerate(zip(range(3), "abc")))
  [(0, (0, 'a')), (1, (1, 'b')), (2, (2, 'c'))]
  ```
- `make_largest_by_swapping_2_digits(digits)` принимает любую изменяемую последовательность (`list`, `bytearray`, `mmap`, etc) c хэшируемыми элементами, которые можно сравнивать.

Например, для больших чисел, записанных в файле, можно с [`mmap`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) напрямую работать (предполагая, что отдельная цифра в байте помещается):

```py
import mmap

with open('много-цифр.txt', 'r+b', 0) as file, \
     mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE) as digits:
    make_largest_by_swapping_2_digits(digits)
```

После выполнения кода, файл `много-цифр.txt` будет содержать новое число—изменение по месту происходит.

Comment: Круто, у Питона есть даже специальный класс для counting sort по сути.

Comment: @VladD Counter по сути  multiset здесь (набор цифр с повторениями). Если ограничить тип цифр только целыми десятичными, то можно простой массив использовать вместо Counter: `multiplicity = [0]*10; for d in digits: multiplicity[d]+=1` (это всё что Counter делает в первом примере).

Comment: Результат `1234` -> `4231` это для одной перестановки? Для запрашиваемых 2-х imho должно получиться `4321`. / А также мне кажется, что задача в полном объеме (с 2-мя перестановками) тоже решается максимум за 2 полных прохода по всему числу, если во вспомогательной таблице цифр держать кроме их количества еще и индексы последнего и предпоследнего вхождения цифры в число, которые находятся при подсчете к-ва каждой цифры на первом проходе (конечно, код будет довольно ужасный)

Comment: @avp: правильный ответ: `4231`, а не `4321` (вопрос явный пример содержит)—в вопросе есть ограничение на обмен: можно только одну пару цифр поменять местами и всё. Если вы хотите получить наибольшее число, то достаточно `largest` вывести (из примера в ответе)—это даже проще (по коду) задача была бы.

Comment: Оооо, прошу прощения! Я вопрос неправильно прочел. Не за 2 обмена, а только 2 цифры (**один обмен**). Это в корне все упрощает (хотел уже написать прогу, но теперь не интересно-))

Comment: @avp: алгоритм, основан на идее используемой в [`std::next_permutation()` из С++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30425798/4279)

Comment: Ну, да. Идем по цифрам от старшей  и считаем их количество в начале числа. Как только нашли несоответствие, меняем с самой правой такой цифрой в числе. Максимум 2 просмотра цифр числа (если оно уже самое большое)